# идентификатор последней вставленной записи

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос на вставку:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tblOrder (
             CustomerID,DateOrder,TimeOrder,TypePurchID,TotalSum,DeliveryID
          )
          VALUES (
             '$idcustomer',CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIME,'$typepurch','$summ','$delivery'
          )";
$add = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Как мне получить идентификатор этой записи (т.е. последней)? Идентификатор проставляется автоматически `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть функция [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/mysqli.insert_id) - возвращает автоматически генерируемый ID, используя последний запрос.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверка соединения */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Соединение не установлено: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
mysqli_query($link, $query);

printf ("ID новой записи: %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($link));

/* удаление таблицы */
mysqli_query($link, "DROP TABLE myCity");

/* закрытие соединения */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: вопрос такой: это id равно id записи в таблице? Все, понял, вопрос исчерпан, спасибо)